# Custom Search DOM Elements

Tags: javascript, dom

I am writing a custom method to return the DOM element reference but it seems to work on all modern browsers such as Chrome,Firefox,Safari but fails in IE 9 ... returned element is undefined it states i am not sure what i am doing wrong

```
var searchEle = function (parent, ref) {
var refEle;
if (typeof document.getElementByClassName === "function") {
    if (ref.substr(0, 1) === ".") {
        refEle = parent.getElementsByClassName(ref.replace(".", ""));
    } else {
        refEle = parent.getElementsByTagName(ref);
    }
} else {
    if (ref.substr(0, 1) === "#") {
        refEle = parent.getElementById(ref.replace("#", ""));
    } else if (ref.substr(0, 1) === ".") {
        refEle = parent.querySelector(ref);
    }
}
return refEle;
};
```

Check out demo here on IE9: http://jsbin.com/ubokop/5/edit

Thanks

Comment: By the way: Every major browser has `document.getElementById` implemented, and even if not it wouldn't have `querySelector` implemented!

Comment: What @DanLee said, and you're also either returning a single DOM element, or a array of elements. That's rather inconsistent.

Comment: @DanLee Hey Dan I do get your point but as i needed a fallback for older IE browser such as 8 and below .. So i had go on with this approach generic method to return the reference element ..

Comment: But there's no browser that will go into the main `else` statement because the initial `if` condition will be true for all. And it is not reasonable to assume that because `getElementById()` is a function that `getElementsByClassName()` will also exist...

Comment: @AjainVivek `getElementById()` **[is supported by IE 5.5+](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#gettingelements)** .
You don't need to write compatibility functions for that. At very least, don't check for `getElementById()`, and then try to use `getElementsByClassName`. Also, the only browser that doesn't support `getElementsByClassName`, but does support `querySelector`, is IE 8, so your fallback will fail in most cases. (Most browsers that don't support `getElementsByClassName`, don't support `querySelector` either.)

Comment: On another note: **Please take down that blog post. There's enough misinformation on the internet as it is.** We don't need another blog spreading information that's simply wrong.

Comment: Signature was removed. You have your profile for that..

Comment: @Cerbrus Thanks for your info ... but can u tell me the reason why is the corrected above code returning undefined only in IE 9 & 8 ... for your kind info I need only fallback support for IE 8 not other browsers thts y i have provided querySelector as fallback...

Comment: The linked demo appears to return proper values for all 3 cases in IE9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use this polyfill for `getElementsByClassName`, since that's really the only function that requires one. It's not perfect, but it's close enough.

```
// Add a getElementsByClassName function if the browser doesn't have one
// Limitation: only works with one class name
// Copyright: Eike Send http://eike.se/nd
// License: MIT License
if (!document.getElementsByClassName) {
    document.getElementsByClassName = function(search) {
        var d = document, elements, pattern, i, results = [];
        if (d.querySelectorAll) { // IE8
            return d.querySelectorAll("." + search);
        }
        if (d.evaluate) { // IE6, IE7
            pattern = ".//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' " + search + " ')]";
            elements = d.evaluate(pattern, d, null, 0, null);
            while (i = elements.iterateNext()) {
                results.push(i);
            }
        } else {
            elements = d.getElementsByTagName("*");
            pattern = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + search + "(\\s|$)");
            for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                if ( pattern.test(elements[i].className) ) {
                    results.push(elements[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

**([Source of this polyfill](https://gist.github.com/eikes/2299607))**

Then, this would be enough:

```
var searchEle = function (ref) {
    if (ref.charAt(0) === "#") {
        return document.getElementById(ref.substr(1));
    }else if (ref.charAt(0) === ".") {
        return document.getElementsByClassName(ref.substr(1));
    }else{
        return document.getElementsByTagName(ref);
    }
};
```